# Refatorar um banco de dados utilizando VIEWS

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, refatoração, padrão-dao

Tenho a tarefa de refatorar um banco de dados e gostaria de saber se `VIEWs` são viáveis para a tarefa.
Minha estratégia é criar uma `VIEW` imitando a nova estrutura da suposta tabela, pelo menos o nome da tabela (nome da `VIEW`) e dos campos (aliases das colunas), até que se confirmem as mudanças e eu possa criar a `TABLE` de fato.
A preocupação que eu tenho é quanto a performance e viabilidade de integrar as `VIEWS` com a camada `DAO`, a qual também ainda estou implementando.
A camada de `DAO` vou implementar de qualquer forma, seja refletindo as `VIEWS` ou `TABLES`, e escolhi `VIEWS` para justamente impactá-la em pouco ou mesmo nada.

Gostaria de saber se alguém já fez algo parecido e se essa estratégia com `VIEWs` é viável para refatorar um banco de dados conforme a situação descrita.

PS1:
Pretendo construir as `VIEWs` seguindo as instruções dessa [parte da documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html), que define quando as `VIEWs` são *insertable*/*updatable*.
O BD atual conta com 150+ tabelas, e algumas tabelas chegam a ter 50+ colunas. O sistema é escrito em PHP sem nenhum padrão ou arquitetura. Há vários `JOINs`, uns fazem sentido e outros não, e a intenção vai ser reescrever grande parte das queries, pois a performance delas é deplorável.
O banco não segue nenhum padrão de normalização, mas como é uma estrutura enorme, creio que vá gerar uma estrutura um tanto quanto complexa nesses termos depois de remodelá-la.
Outra coisa para considerar, vai ser que a nova estrutura e a velha vão habitar o mesmo banco de dados, só vou poder me desfazer da antiga estrutura no final do projeto, quanto ela já estiver completamente obsoleta.
O DAO idealmente deveria suportar tanto as tabelas físicas como as `VIEWs`, mas creio que eu poderia criar um DAO para cada caso.

PS2: A biblioteca pretendida para se usar vai ser a [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/)
DDL de parte de uma tabela atual:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios {
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` varchar(16) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `flag_ativo` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ON' #ativo ou nao varia entre ON e OFF, respectivamente
}
```

Exemplo de uma `VIEW`, onde o resultado refletiria a tabela reestruturada:

```
SELECT
    `Usuarios`.`id` AS `cd_usuario`,
    `Usuarios`.`user_name` AS `de_usuario`,
    `Usuarios`.`user_pass` AS `de_senha`,
    IF ((`Usuarios`.`flag_ativo` = 'ON'), 1, 0) AS `fl_ativo`
FROM
    `Usuarios`
```

Um DAO pretendido, refletindo a `VIEW` que seria a tabela real já remodela:

```
class Usuarios extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    //table_name é um atributo da ActiveRecord\Model
    static $table_name = 'tb_usuarios';

    //Também atributo da ActiveRecord\Model
    static $primary_key = 'cd_usuario';

    //De uso interno da classe, faria isso para cada campo
    static $de_usuario = 'de_usuario';

    static $de_senha = 'de_senha';

    static $fl_ativo = 'fl_ativo';

    public function validaLogin($user, $pass) {
        $usuario = self::first(
                     array('conditions' => 
                         array(
                             self::$de_usuario.' = ? AND '.
                             self::$de_senha.' = ? AND '.
                             self::$fl_ativo.' = ?', 
                             $user, 
                             md5($pass),
                             1
                         )
                     )
        );
        return $usuario !== null;
    }
}
```

Comment: views em geral não permitem insert, assim  não funcionaria em sua plenitude, dependendo do SGBD ou da implementação da DAO, pode-se utilizar da view para ler, e a tabela real para escrever.
Em postgres pode-se criar ações para tratar um insert em uma view, desconheço a existência disso em mysql.
Talvez se detalhar um pouco mais podemos te ajudar.

Comment: @Gregoriobonfante vou atualizar a pergunta esclarecendo um pouco mais, levando em conta suas considerações

Comment: @Gregoriobonfante Será que um DAO para VIEW e um DAO para a tabela física seria melhor?

Comment: Então, n sei como é a implementação que vc esta utilizando, como exemplo vou falar de um algo mais comum como o Laravel, nele vc pode modificar a foma como é trabalhado (com um médio esforço) e na mesma model usar uma view para leitura e uma tabela para escrita.
Tudo depende da solução, não consigo saber o quanto vai mudar de uma table para view, se forma mudanças simples, consegue fazer em qualquer uma ( como separar uma table em varias views ou o inverso, onde varias tables se tornam uma view).

Comment: Minha sugestão, faça a rescrita da estrutura, assim que tiver uma estrutura similar ( sem considerar visual), migre os dados que já tiverem 'lugar'. dependendo do tempo disponível faça teste para ver se esta 'valendo' fazer a migração. Medir o tempo é importante, mas em muitos casos o principal problema esta no infra. Já trabalhei com bancos mal estruturados, digo que em alguns casos valeu mais a pena utilizar de técnicas menos trabalhosas, para falar de algumas soluções claro que depende dos pontos que se deseja otimizar, trabalhar no 'frontend' como reduzir css/js e utilizar cache é uma boa.

Comment: Nas consultas também se pode utilizar cache, principalmente nessas mais demoradas. As views de um banco por mais que ajudem acabam por ser 'query salvas', valendo mais a pena utilizar elas quando se pode filtrar parte dos dados, como remover alguns registros que não existam em outras tabelas etc.. do contrario acaba por ser um mero mascaramento.
No caso de sistema em produção onde se tem pouco tempo para apresentar melhora, recomendo ir para o fácil como cache,  views incrementais (Tabelas físicas alimentadas por ações em outras tabelas).

Comment: Se possível, forneça parte da estrutura de tabelas e da sua implementação de acesso. tanto atual quanto o que é pretendido. Acredito que ficaria mais fácil de lhe ajudar.

Comment: Primeiro, obrigado pela ajuda até agora. Decidi usar essa [biblioteca](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/) pra fazer acesso aos dados. O acesso atual é feito diretamente pelas funções mysql_* e às vezes mysqli_*. Acho que se eu fornecer parte da estrutura vou quebrar algumas regras de privacidade, então vou replicar com o máximo de fidelidade a estrutura real.

Comment: uma boa alternativa, existem outras soluções que contam com mais colaboradores, se busca um active record, tente o laravel, o eloquent utilizado por ele usa o mesmo pattern.

Comment: Na verdade decidi a biblioteca não levando em conta o pattern usado, mas sim a flexibilidade/facilidade de uso. Já dei início no projeto e infelizmente não posso me comprometer com curvas de aprendizado. Aliás, busco uma camada bem fina de acesso aos dados, não algo tão robusto que permita eu mudar de banco de dados ou coisa parecida, pois sei que não vai acontecer mesmo.

Comment: Na verdade agora percebi que o que busco é uma abstração de código que me permita, caso quando a VIEW não for updateable/insertable, consiguir usar a tabela real. Talvez uma Entity abstraindo isso, ou até duas, se for preciso. Você teria algo em mente?

Comment: Então, depende do caso. Você consegue isso com Doctrine via evento, o Eloquent também, são patterns diferentes.
Apesar da curva com Eloquent ser mais simples eu não gosto muito da abordagem. 
Mas no Eloquente você pode ver q a Class Model tem metodos como o `performInsert`, nele você poderia alterar a table.
Só entenda que dependendo do que se deseja a menor curva pode ter um preço no final.
Como falei antes, também depende da diferença entre as Views e as Tabelas

Comment: Uma alternativa mais rápida,  use umas models para ação de criar e atualizar e outras somente como leitura.